# Jquery calling a function on click

Tags: jquery

script:

```
window.onload = function(){

    $("a.prevent-default").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault(); 
    });

 };
function add(exp){
//x
    $("a").click(function(){

        $(".first").append('<div class="'+exp+'"></div>');


    });
}
```

The problem is that every time i execute this function onclick no. of divs added/appended is doubled, but i want only one block to append on one click.

Please Help!

Comment: you need to remove the previously added handlers.. so `$("a").off('click.exp').on('click.exp', function () {
    $(".first").append('<div class="' + exp + '"></div>');
});`

Comment: where do you call this add() function ;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of appending, you can use `.html()` this will replace the entire contents, rather than adding to the contents:

```
 $(".first").html('<div class="'+exp+'"></div>');
```

You could also empty the element first, then append:

```
 $(".first").empty();
 $(".first").append('<div class="'+exp+'"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(exp){
  $("a").click(function(event){
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevent-default')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(".first").append('<div class="'+exp+'"></div>');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That's when you don't want to 'prevent default' class to append. Otherwise move append from else section to above if statement.